# QNetworkReply doesn't abort/close

Tags: python, networking, pyqt, pyside, timing

## EDIT:

I've prepared this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for your convenience: (just run it)

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest, QNetworkReply
import time
import sys
import json

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

class SSCCE(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 578)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def main(self):
        request = QNetworkRequest()
        request.setUrl(QUrl("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue&rpp=1"))

        self.network_manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.network_manager.finished.connect(self._request_finished)        

        self.network_manager.post(request, self.urlencode_post({'a' : 'b'}))

    def urlencode_post(self, data):
        post_params = QUrl()
        for (key, value) in data.items():
            post_params.addQueryItem(key, unicode(value))            

        return post_params.encodedQuery()

    def func2(self):
        request = QNetworkRequest()
        request.setUrl(QUrl("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=red&rpp=1"))
        request.setRawHeader('content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8')
        self.network_manager.finished.connect(self.func3)
        self.network_manager.get(request)

    def func3(self, reply):
        if not reply.error() == QNetworkReply.NoError:
            # request probably failed
            print(reply.error())
            print(reply.errorString())
        else:
            reply.close()

    def func1(self, reply):
        ans = reply.readAll()
        print(ans)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("""\n 
IT PRINTS THEM BOTH:
===================
%s
"""%ans)
        self.func2()

    def _request_finished(self, reply):
        if not reply.error() == QNetworkReply.NoError:
            # request probably failed
            print(reply.error())
            print(reply.errorString())
        else:
            reply.close()
            self.func1(reply)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QMainWindow()
ui = SSCCE()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
ui.main()

MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

## ORIGINAL QUESTION:

**My Code: (relevent parts)**

```
    def update(self):
        request = QNetworkRequest()
        request.setUrl(QUrl("someurl"))
        self.network_manager.finished.connect(self._update)
        self.network_manager.get(request)

    def _update(self, reply): # update stage 2    
        if not reply.error() == QNetworkReply.NoError:
            # request probably failed
            print(reply.error())
            print(reply.errorString())
            print("retrying")
            self.update()
        else:
            reply.abort()
            #print(str(reply.readAll().data()))
            data = json.loads(str(reply.readAll().data())) # get data
            #work with the data (irrelevant)

    def sendBearer_req(self):

        request = QNetworkRequest()
        request.setUrl(QUrl("someotherurl"))

        self.network_manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.network_manager.finished.connect(self._request_finished)        

        self.network_manager.post(request, self.urlencode_post({'some' : 'thing'}))

    def sendBearer(self, reply):
        reply.abort()
        ans = reply.readAll()        
        print(ans)
        time.sleep(5)
        print(ans)

        try:
            self.bearer = json.loads(str(ans))                
            self.update()            
        except:
            raise #for debugging
            self.sendBearer_req() #retry        

    def _request_finished(self, reply):
        if not reply.error() == QNetworkReply.NoError:
            # request probably failed
            print(reply.error())
            print(reply.errorString())
            print("retrying")
            self.sendBearer_req()
        else:
            self.sendBearer(reply)
```

**Problem:**

in this part:

```
reply.abort()
ans = reply.readAll()        
print(ans)
time.sleep(5)
print(ans)
```

I'm pretty sure the `abort` isn't working because on the first `print` it prints just what i want but then, while it waits, apparently it continues with the code and enters the `update` function where it sends another request. Therefor in the second `print` the two replies mix together and it prints the both.

(btw I tried `close` as well - same result)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your issue. `finished` signal will be emitted for each request. So `_request_finished` is called for each request. And you print the same string twice, with a sleep in between. Obviously, it'll print it twice. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Avaris my problem was not that it printed it twice but that on the second print it printed the original value + the result from the second request. look at my answer to see how I fixed it :)

Comment: Second print doesn't print both. Second print prints a reply and that function is called again with another reply. Since you have a sleep in between, the network request completes in the meantime. So second call happens immediately after the first one. The printed results you see are respectively, 'second print from previous call' and 'first print from next call'.

Comment: Now that i looked again, actually your second request is called after the sleep. But it's a short reply, so it's completed quite fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem!

The problem was that I haven't disconnected the network manager `finished` signal from the former function it was connected to, therefore causing the reply to go to both functions (new connection and the old one)

I solved it using the `.disconnect()` command just before connecting it again:

```
self.network_manager.finished.disconnect() #this!!!
self.network_manager.finished.connect(self._update)
```

and in the SSCCE:

```
self.network_manager.finished.disconnect() #this!!!
self.network_manager.finished.connect(self.func3)
```

Hope I helped you future viewers!